# scrollToIndex doesn't scroll the list in React-virtualized list

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

With [`react-virtualized`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized), when you scroll the `list` and set the same `scrollToIndex`, it doesn't scroll back to the same index.

Is there a way to reset the list back to the position?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the prop hasn't changed. You can use the scrollToCell or scrollToRow method (depending on whether you're using Grid or List/Table) to re-scroll to the same index.

Comment: How to use `scrollToRow` method? `List` is a React component so can't do `List.scrollToRow`.

Answer (score 0):

As @brianvaughn also said, you List doesn't scroll to the index back again because to the props to the react-virtualized list component haven't changed.

Since, By default all `react-virtualized` components use `shallowCompare` to avoid re-rendering unless `props` or `state` has changed. The components won't re-render until an update has happened.

The solution to this is to let `react-virtualized` know that something external has changed. This can be done a couple of different ways.

Also its mentioned in the documentation that you have two ways to let `react-virtualized` know that something has changed

**Pass-thru props**

The shallowCompare method will detect changes to any props, even if they aren't declared as propTypes. This means you can also pass through additional properties that affect cell rendering to ensure changes are detected. So you could pass additional props that change when you fire an event that for the `virtualized` list doesn't change anything.

```
<List
  {...listProps}
  sortBy={sortBy}
/>
```

**Public methods**

Grid and Collection components can be forcefully re-rendered using `forceUpdate`. For Table and List, you'll need to call `forceUpdateGrid` to ensure that the inner Grid is also updated.

So whenever you wish to update the `scrollToIndex` if, its value hasn't changed from the previous value you could call `forceUpdateGrid` on the List. This method can come in handy in a lot of other situations as well

Having said that, it may not be the best option always as there is another option to force scroll event if the `scrollToIndex` hasn't changed, which is the `scrollToRow`  option. However it requires the row you want to scroll to be visible. Its its not, you won't be able to use it.

**scrollToRow (index: number)**

> Ensure row is visible. This method can be used to safely scroll back
>   to a cell that a user has scrolled away from even if it was previously
>   scrolled to.